# Polymer: Can i replace native HTML element with polymer's

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, polymer

F.e. i have elements on website like this:

```
<input type="text">
```

Can i replace them with paper-input, f.e.? The problem is, i using Drupal, there is many forms generated by Form API and other elements. Replace  them all to paper - is pain or not can be done, so i looking for method to replace default html elements with polymer's.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something you would need to do through Drupal or their templating system. You can't really overwrite the native HTML elements that it's outputting to the DOM. You would need to either have the Forms API output paper-inputs instead, or you would have to replace them all with JavaScript created elements, which wouldn't be very efficient.

Comment: Tank you for answer, i always think altering Drupal fapi system but no sure it's will work. If i do, i comment it again.

Answer (score 0):

Polymer permits the [extension of native elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#type-extension)

Additionally, you can wrap the existing input in [paper-input-container](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container) to achieve the same result as using paper-input (this is how paper-input works)

```
<paper-input-container>
<label>Your name</label>
<input is="iron-input">
</paper-input-container>
```

There's not going to be any easy way besides editing your Drupal form templates.

Comment: I tried <input is="iron-input"> <input is="paper-input"> on plain html an this is does not working for me :( I import them in head for sure. Only <paper-input> works fine